# observeEvent() function in R

Tags: r, shiny

I an super new to R and was exploring different buttons. I came acorss observe event and tried to use it, but it does not print my output. Can someone please help!

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
sliderInput(inputId = "num",
label = "Choose a number",
value = 25, min = 1, max = 100),
actionButton(inputId = "go", label = "Print Value")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
observeEvent(input$go,{as.numeric(input$num)})
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Note: The function is a part of the shiny library

Comment: Hi.  This function doesn't seem to be a part of `base` R. Could you let me know where it is from (i.e., which package)? Thanks.

Comment: the 'shiny' library. my bad, I'll update my question

Comment: Ok. I don't use Shiny so I will leave this one for someone else to answer. I would suggest adding 'shiny' as a tag to get the right person here. All the best.

Comment: Try `print(input$num)` inside your `observeEvent`.  `observeEvent` is a function and, just like any function, you need to print to see output from "inside" the function.  Also, a `sliderInput` returns numeric values, so you don't need the `as.numeric`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to print to the console you'll need to call `print`. If you rather want to print in the UI, you can do this with a `reactiveVal`:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sliderInput(inputId = "num",
              label = "Choose a number",
              value = 25, min = 1, max = 100),
  actionButton(inputId = "go", label = "Print Value"),
  textOutput("myText")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  printData <- reactiveVal()
  
  observeEvent(input$go,{
    print(input$num) # print to console
    printData(input$num) # pass data to reactiveVal
    })
  
  output$myText <- renderText(printData())
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```